# How to get Chinese year from date time in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, datetime

It is a simple task using the .Net Framework, because it has the `ChineseLunisolarCalendar` class. Chinese year may be obtained like this:

```
ChineseLunisolarCalendar calendar = new ChineseLunisolarCalendar();
var someDate = new DateTime(1984,2,1);
var chineseYear = calendar.GetYear(someDate);// will be 1983
```

Is there an equivalent of this construct available in Windows phone?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the Mono implementation of all related classes in your project to fill the gaps,

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Globalization/ChineseLunisolarCalendar.cs